# Unknow mysql store function syntax error

Tags: mysql, function

Here is my store function, There is no compile error but every time executing it, errors appears and i don't know how to resolve it, any help will be appreciated!

```
 CREATE FUNCTION splitAssociatedGene(IN associateGenes TEXT)
  RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    DECLARE return_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    IF length(trim(associateGenes)) = 0 OR associateGenes IS NULL THEN
      SET return_val = 0;
    ELSEIF locate(associateGenes, ',') = 0 THEN
      SET return_val = 1;
    ELSE
      SET return_val = round((length(associateGenes)-length(replace(associateGenes, ',', '')))/length(','));
    END IF;
    RETURN return_val;
  END;
```

Here is error message(Too common and boring-.-):

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN associateGenes TEXT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE return_val INT;
' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql function parameters don't accept `In` or `OUT` in its syntax due to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html see `func_parameter`

So you should update your function like this

```
    CREATE FUNCTION splitAssociatedGene(associateGenes text)
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE return_val INT DEFAULT 0;
        IF length(trim(associateGenes)) = 0 OR associateGenes IS NULL THEN
          SET return_val = 0;
        ELSEIF locate(associateGenes, ',') = 0 THEN
          SET return_val = 1;
        ELSE
          SET return_val = round((length(associateGenes)-length(replace(associateGenes, ',', '')))/length(','));
        END IF;
        RETURN return_val;
    END;
```